# How to send 5,000+ emails at once?

Tags: email, singleemailmessage

I have to send emails to around 10-15,000 customers at the start of each month but salesforce only allows for 5,000 emails to be sent per day. How do i go about setting up a batch to run through 5,000 emails then the next day 5,000 more, until they are all sent.

Or if anyone has any other ideas how to approach this problem please don't hesitate to say, any ideas are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: What's the purpose of these emails? There's several ways I can think of, but it really depends on the intent of these emails.

Comment: If the 'customers' are captured in SObjects (like Contact), then you can use workflow/process builder to send email alerts and your governor limits will, in most cases, be larger than 5,000 per day -- depends on your Edition and # of users. see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=limits_email_workflow.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Comment: I'm currently working on an in depth solution I'll upload tomorrow should it work

Answer (score 1):

You're not easily going to be able to send that kind of volume with Salesforce alone. Sure, you can batch them up as you suggested, but then you will have potential scalability problems. What if you suddenly want to do two mailshots per month? What about any other emails you are sending - if you've used your SF allowance on these big batches, you might not have capacity for those.

If they are marketing emails, and you want to get into marketing automation, then consider using Marketing Cloud, or Pardot.

If you just want to send lots of email simply and relatively cheaply, you will need to make callouts to a specialist email delivery service. I've used both SendGrid and Amazon SES for these purposes. I slightly prefer SendGrid, but it's a bit of a matter of taste which is more appropriate.